# MySQL is failing granting permission to database for database user

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a database and a new database user. I am trying to grant all permissions to that newly created user for the new database.

But I am failing:

- DB is being created successfully
- DB User is being created successfully
- But granting permission is not successful

It is not showing any error. I have tried to log in using the new user and password. I can login, but I cannot see the db, means grant is not ok.

Please see my code:

```
        $username = "bdsat_boishakhi29";
        $password = $username;
        $databasename = $username; 

        $admin_db = "mysql";
        $admin_user = "bdsat";
        $admin_password = "demo123456";

        $connection=mysqli_connect("localhost",$admin_user,$admin_password);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "<br>Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }else{
            echo "<br>Connected XXX";
        } 

        $sql="CREATE DATABASE $databasename";

        if (mysqli_query($connection,$sql))
        {
            echo "<br>Database <b>$databasename</b> created successfully!";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<br>Error  creating database: " . mysqli_error($connection);
        }

        // Create user 
        $sql="CREATE USER '".$username."'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '".$password."'"; 

        if (mysqli_query($connection,$sql))
        {
           echo "<p>User Created... <b>$databasename</b> created successfully!</p>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<br>Error creating database user: " . mysqli_error($connection);
        }


        // Grant user permissions  
        $sql="GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $databasename.* TO $username@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY $password"; 

        $connection=mysqli_connect("localhost",$admin_user,$admin_password);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "<br>Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }else{
            echo "<br>Connected XXX";
        } 

        if (mysqli_query($sql))
        {
           echo "<p>User permissions Created... <b>$databasename</b> created successfully!</p>";
        }
        else
        {
           echo "<br>Error granting database permission: " . mysqli_error($connection2);
        } 

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r(mysqli_query("SHOW GRANTS FOR $username@'localhost'"));
```

Comment: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $databasename.* TO $username@'localhost'`  --  If you are not using `localhost` as your DB connection, this will fail.  If you are using an IP IE `192.168.0.2` OR if you're using Localhost's IP --> `127.0.0.1` --  You need to specify that in the query IE `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $databasename.* TO $username@'127.0.0.1'`  OR `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $databasename.* TO $username@'192.168.0.1'` --  Secondly you need to flush privileges AFTER granting the permissions --> `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: Also it's worth noting that **In addition** to that original `GRANT` statement --  You should use this: **as well** : `GRANT ALL ON database.* to user@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`  The `%` allows remote connections -- So you will have **2** `GRANT` statements per user.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I am going to try it and letting you know.

Comment: Did you `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after granting them?  Some examples recommend that though they might be outdated.

Comment: I have tried this code 
                        `// Create user  
   $sql="CREATE USER $username@'000.000.000.00' IDENTIFIED BY $password 
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $databasename.* TO $username@'000.000.000.00' 
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES";   

   if (mysqli_query($connection,$sql)) 
   { 
      echo "<p>User Created... <b>$username</b> created successfully!</p>"; 
   }else{ 
    echo "<br>Error creating database user: " . mysqli_error($connection); 
   }`

But it is showing that:
You have an error in your SQL syntax 

@Zak and @Dave S